# vue.js - passing selected option string data from <childComponent1/> to <childComponent2/>

Tags: vue.js

I have this block of code in `<oneChildComponent />`, based on `<select>` element:

```js
new Vue({
      template:'
      <select v-model="selectedOption" @change="handleChange">
          <option value="" disabled>--Select--</option>
          <option v-for="item in data" :value="item.val">
              {{item.text}} 
          </option>
      </select>
    ',
    data:{
       selectedOption:''
    },
    methods:{
        handleChange:function(event){
          console.log(this.selectedOption); //you will find the value here
        }
    }
})
```

The goal is to take a string value of `selectedOption` and pass it from `<oneChildComponent />` to `<anotherChildComponent />`. Those components are contained in main parent component.
Is it possible to modify this `handleChange()` method with `$emit()`, and what's the best way to do it?

I'me new with vue.js, so thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply emit the changed value to the parent:

```
handleChange: function(event){
    this.$emit("valueChanged", this.selectedOption);
}
```

In the parent, you need to define a variable, in which the emitted value is stored, and a function for assigning it.

```
{
    data: function() {
        return {
             myValue: ""
        }
    },
    methods: {
        setValue(value) {
             this.myValue = value;
        }
    }

}
```

Also in the parent, you then can intercept this emit and set this value by doing:

```
<oneChildComponent @valueChanged="setValue"/>
```

Finally, you have to pass myValue to your second child component as prop:

```
<anotherChildComponent :myValue="myValue" />
```

This variable is available in this child component by declaring it as a prop:

```
{
    props: {
        myValue: String
    }
}
```